# NSSortDescriptor for coredata one-to-many relationsip

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

All I want to know is how to set `NSSortDescriptor` to `NSFetchRequest`.

Can't we perform sort by comparator in `CoreData`?

Any other work around?
Any suggestions to change my model to facilitate that?

BTW, I will have no clue in advance what type of recordValue I will be adding, I will have variable number of recordvalue in all the possible combinations.

[image]

I have core data model as shown and data is stored as given below

(When I want to sort by dateValue, the dataValue of DOB should only be considered for sorting)

```
id    stringValue<NSString>  dateValue<NSDate>     record


name     Alex                     -            record1<ZCMORecord>

DOB      -                     10/10/1990      record1<ZCMORecord>

name     Anto                     -            record2<ZCMORecord>

DOB      -                     05/05/1990      record2<ZCMORecord>

name     Max                     -            record3<ZCMORecord>

DOB      -                     10/10/1990      record3<ZCMORecord>

name     Mary                     -            record4<ZCMORecord>

DOB      -                     01/01/1990      record4<ZCMORecord>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you sort a `NSFetchedResultsController`:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
        entityForName:@"ZCMORecordValue" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortStringValue = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
        initWithKey:@"stringValue" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDate = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
        initWithKey:@"dateValue" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortStringValue, sortDate]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
        [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
            managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil
            cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

This will sort first by the name and then by the date. Invert the order of the sort descriptors if you want to sort by the date and then by the name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @SpaceDog. Let me try this and get back

Comment: It wouldn't work :(.. lets say I have an id 'addedTime' along with name and DOB. adddedTime would be a NSDate. So when I sort, it is also taken into account. which will work wrong.
All i want is, I want to specify the Id as DOB and then sort. :(
I am even open to change the model.

Comment: what is DOB? what parameter do you want to use for sorting?